# Used 5 colors for making a 12 X 6 matrix. Is their a software to depict the combinations?

Tags: permutations

I have used $5$ colors for making a $12 \times  6 $ matrix.
What are the possible combinations? Is there a software to depict those combinations? Thanks

Comment: The number of combinations: $5^{72}$.

Answer (score 1):

If you include results with less than five colors, this number is $5^{12*6}$, since you have five choices of color for each entry.

If you want each color to appear at least once, this is the number of surjective maps from a $12*6=72$ element set to a 5 element set. This number is 
$$5!{72 \brace 5},$$ where the curly braces refer to Stirling Numbers of the Second Kind.